# HTTPS and RSS feeds. Why are they only HTTP?

Tags: https, rss

My checkout page isn't 100% secure, and it's because of my RSS feeds.  When I go to my page with HTTPS, everything loads with HTTPS (css files and stuff),  EXCEPT for RSS feeds. They still load with HTTP.

Is there a way to get Magento to use HTTPS with RSS links?

Comment: Are you positive that it's your RSS link? Are you getting any errors? An insecure URL will not cause warnings saying that a page has insecure content, however assets actually used on the page such as css, images and iframes will.

Comment: If I view-source the checkout page, the only thing I can find that doesn't use HTTPS is the RSS links in the header.

Comment: Use chrome and look in the javascript console. Apparently recent versions will show the exact offending file.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728507/finding-all-insecure-content-on-a-secure-page

Comment: You are a genius, thank you.  One of the extensions I'm using has http:// hardcoded in their code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please review this post that goes over the various methods of finding insecure content on a page as a simple URL would not cause an insecure content error. Assets such as css, images, js and others will. As well as insecure content pulled through those assets such as inside javascript source.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728507/finding-all-insecure-content-on-a-secure-page